# C# Calendar Object on top

Tags: c#

Hi programming some C# in a form with a bunch of group boxes.  I have a two Calendar controls that when called upon, are partially invisible due to surrounding group boxes.

```
this.grp_TransactionDetails.Controls.Add(this.cal_Ctrl);
this.grp_TransactionDetails.Controls.Add(this.cal_Batch);
```

Any ideas? (I wish there was a z-index property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I had to actually change the order in which the controls were added to the form.  I changed the order in the Initialze() method of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Controls in .Net have a `BringToFront()` method that might be what you need.  Calling this method on a control brings it to the front of the z-order (`SendToBack()` has the opposite effect, as you might expect).